# Sending binary file content using JSON

Tags: php, json, rest, file-get-contents, owncloud

I've written a REST interface for my ownCloud app. I've method `getFileFromRemote($path)` which should return a JSON object with the file content.
Unfortunately this only works when the file that I've specified in `$path` is a plaintext file. When I try to call the method for an image or `PDF` the status code is 200 but the response is empty. For returning the file contents I use `file_get_contents` for retrieving the content.

---

**Note:** I know ownCloud has a WebDAV interface, but I want to solve this with REST only.

---

**EDIT**
This is the code server side (ownCloud):

```
public function synchroniseDown($path)
{
    $this->_syncService->download(array($path));//get latest version
    $content = file_get_contents($this->_homeFolder.urldecode($path));
    return new DataResponse(['path'=>$path, 'fileContent'=>$content]);
}
```

The first line retrieves downloades the content on the ownCloud server and works completely.

Comment: Bit of code receiving and delivering content wiil be helpful.

Comment: I've added some code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have to `base64_encode` your file content to make json_encode/decode handle it properly:

```
return new DataResponse([
    'path'=>$path,
    'fileContent' => base64_encode($content)  // convert binary data to alphanum
]);
```

and then when receiving file via second side, you will have to always:

```
$fileContent = base64_decode($response['fileContent']);
```

It's only one, but ones of easiest way to handle that. Btw, sooner or later you will find that `Mime-Type` would be useful in response.